# В Chrome не отображаются define и массивы php

Tags: php, массивы, google-chrome, opera

Драсте. Пытался сделать локализацию сайта, чтобы типо можно было переключать языки. Вродь всё получилось, кроме одного. Пускаю сайт в Опере - пашет всё на ура. Открываю Chrome - пурга. Когда стояли дефайны - их имена отображались, поменял на массив - вообще ничерта не показывает.

```
<header>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="/"><svg style="margin: 25px 0; width: 135px; height: 20px; fill: #3E66AC; display: block;">
                <use xlink:href="#logo"></use>
            </svg></a>
        </div>
        <a href="" class="login"><? echo $gl['LANG_REG_LOGIN'] ?></a>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="body">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="form">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <h1 style="text-align: center"><? echo $gl['LANG_REG_REGISTRATION'] ?></h1>
                <span style="display: block; text-align: center; font-size: 12px; line-height: 35px;"><? echo $gl['LANG_REG_GO_ON'] ?></span>
                <? if($errpass) echo $errpass; ?><br>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="<? echo $gl['LANG_REG_NAME'] ?>" required><br>
                <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="<? echo $gl['LANG_REG_SURNAME'] ?>" required><br>
                <div class="rtitle"><? echo $gl['LANG_REG_BIRTHDAY'] ?></div>
                <div class="birthday">
                    <select name="day" required>
                        <?
                            for($i = 1; $i < 31+1; $i++)
                            {
                                echo "<option value='".$i."'>$i</option>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    <select name="month" required style="margin: 0 5px;">
                        <option value="01"><? echo $gl['LANG_REG_JAN'] ?></option>
                        <option value="02"><? echo $gl['LANG_REG_FEB'] ?></option>
                        <option value="03"><? echo $gl['LANG_REG_MAR'] ?></option>
                        <option value="04"><? echo $gl['LANG_REG_APR'] ?></option>
                        <option value="05"><? echo $gl['LANG_REG_MAY'] ?></option>
                        <option value="06"><? echo $gl['LANG_REG_JUN'] ?></option>
                        <option value="07"><? echo $gl['LANG_REG_JUL'] ?></option>
                        <option value="08"><? echo $gl['LANG_REG_AUG'] ?></option>
                        <option value="09"><? echo $gl['LANG_REG_SEP'] ?></option>
                        <option value="10"><? echo $gl['LANG_REG_OCT'] ?></option>
                        <option value="11"><? echo $gl['LANG_REG_NOV'] ?></option>
                        <option value="12"><? echo $gl['LANG_REG_DEC'] ?></option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="year" required>
                        <?
                        yearsdroplist();
                    ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="rtitle"><? echo $gl['LANG_REG_SEX'] ?></div>
                <div class="sex">
                    <label class="inputs"><input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" value="male" required><i></i><label> <label for="male"><? echo $gl['LANG_REG_MALE'] ?></label>
                    <label class="inputs"><input type="radio" name="sex" id="female" value="female" required><i></i><label> <label for="female"><? echo $gl['LANG_REG_FEMALE'] ?></label>
                </div>
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required><br>
                <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="<? echo $gl['LANG_REG_PASSWORD'] ?>" required><br>
                <input type="password" name="rpass" placeholder="<? echo $gl['LANG_REG_REPEAT_PASSWORD'] ?>" required><br>
                <input type="submit" name="reg" class="reg" value="<? echo $gl['LANG_REG_REGISTER'] ?>">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="firstcol">
            <? echo $gl['LANG_COPY'] ?>
        </div>
        <div class="sndcol">
            <? echo $gl['LANG_COPY'] ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Вот код самого яз.пакета:

```
<?
    $gl = array(
    "LANG_COPY" =>                     "&copy 2gather, 2017 г. Все права защищены",
    "LANG_REG_REGISTRATION" =>         "Регистрация",
    "LANG_REG_GO_ON" =>                "Присоединяйся к нам!",
    "LANG_REG_BIRTHDAY" =>             "Дата рождения",
    "LANG_REG_SEX" =>                  "Пол",

    "LANG_REG_NAME" =>                 "Имя",
    "LANG_REG_SURNAME" =>              "Фамилия",

    "LANG_REG_JAN" =>                  "января",
    "LANG_REG_FEB" =>                  "февраля",
    "LANG_REG_MAR" =>                  "марта",
    "LANG_REG_APR" =>                  "апреля",
    "LANG_REG_MAY" =>                  "мая",
    "LANG_REG_JUN" =>                  "июня",
    "LANG_REG_JUL" =>                  "июля",
    "LANG_REG_AUG" =>                  "августа",
    "LANG_REG_SEP" =>                  "сентября",
    "LANG_REG_OCT" =>                  "октября",
    "LANG_REG_NOV" =>                  "ноября",
    "LANG_REG_DEC" =>                  "декабря",

    "LANG_REG_MALE" =>                 "Мужчина",
    "LANG_REG_FEMALE" =>               "Женщина",

    "LANG_REG_PASSWORD" =>             "Пароль",
    "LANG_REG_REPEAT_PASSWORD" =>      "Повторите пароль",

    "LANG_REG_NEXT" =>                 "Далее",

    "LANG_REG_LOGIN" =>                "Войти",
    "LANG_REG_REGISTER" =>             "Зарегистрироваться");
```

Сайт: http://plyussn.esy.es

Comment: Код покажите. По картинкам не гадаем

Comment: Код. Мы не экстрасенсы. Возможно кэш браузера виноват. Пробовали сбрасывать?

Comment: На сколько я знаю, кэш берет только разметку и стили, php-файлы он не загребает. А тут, по ходу, трабл весь в php. Код скинул.

Comment: Вы действительно думаете, что php на сервере работает по разному от того, какой браузер запрос сделал?

Comment: ну а шо тогда с этим делать?

Comment: что делат? - кэш почистить вам уже сказали :) привести серверный код, генерирующий эти страницы, и исходный код страниц, которые вам браузер выдает :)

Comment: Вы выше читали? Кэш PHP-файлы не затаскивает, затаскивает только HTML+CSS, а у меня проблема, по сему видимо, в PHP, т.к. не хочет вытаскивать из языковых пакетов фразы.

Comment: @АртемДобряк , т.е. браузер все-таки мог закешировать HTML до ошибки? А как выглядит в  ФФ? И куда вы скинули код?

Comment: @br3t, блин, видно, не сохранилось. Сейчас добавлю. Насчёт кеширования возможно, но вряд ли. После того я кэш очищал. И где выглядит?

Comment: @АртемДобряк , в Mozilla Firefox. Ну или просто любом, отличным от названных в вопросе, браузере.

Comment: @br3t, на мозилле летает как надо, сафари - аналогично, IE - нет

Comment: @АртемДобряк , я бы на вашем месте убедился в отсутствии браузерного и серверного кэширований.

Answer (score 0):

Я понял в чём цимес после того, как вывел `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` на экран. В Опере показало `ru-RU`, а Chrome - `en-US`. А такого ланг.пака у меня и признаку не было. И тут была вся загвоздка. Всё, всем спасибо, все свободны